# Why is Foundation installation with CodeKit failing?

Tags: zurb-foundation, codekit

I have been using CodeKit for several years now, and this morning I tried to start a new project by downloading Zurb's Foundation but keep getting this error.

```
Foundation: Installation failed. CodeKit cloned Foundation's Git repository to 

your project folder, but it could not download the latest components using Bower. Try these steps to fix the problem:

1. Be sure you're connected to the Internet.
2. If you are running any blocking/security apps like Little Snitch or Antivirus software, disable those.
3. If you have installed Apple's Developer Tools, launch Xcode, accept the license terms and let the installation routine finish.
4. Make sure your network or firewall is not blocking the default port for git:// URLs, which is 9418. (Corporate networks do this frequently.) Use the "Tasks" menu to switch Git to use https:// URLs instead.
5.Delete the following hidden folders in your home directory: ".cache", ".npm", ".local"
```

I followed the 5 steps of what to try, and I'm still not having any luck getting Foundation to install.

Trying to install Foundation 6 via the New Zurb Foundation Project option.

Comment: Same here, have you found solution yet?

Comment: So this was an issue of Zurb changing from Bower to Node, Codekit was updated and this fixed the problem I was having. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You may open Terminal and reset XCode: 
$ sudo xcode-select --reset
Worked for me. Install the command line tools if that does not work: 
$ xcode-select --install 
Good Luck!